# Paginated Rest Call - Java

Tags: java

We need to call a third party service which supports pagination and it can return only example 10 results per call , and the response will contain totalRecords and pageNumber , I have added the below code which we are doing right now . Is this the correct way or can modified to make it more efficient ?

```
defaultPageSize = 10;
defaultPageNumber  =1;
Response response = call3rdPartyService(defaultPageSize,defaultPageNumber,request);
totalRecords = response.totalRecords();

pageNumberToIterate = (totalRecords + defaultPageSize -1 ) / defaultPageSize;


for(int i=2;i<=pageNumberToIterate ;i++){
    call3rdPartyService(defaultPageSize,i,request);
}
```

Comment: Do you need to fetch all page data ?

Comment: @Eklavya: yes if they have data more than the pageSize

Comment: Did you check in response totalNumber of page returned  or not ?

Comment: If there is no way to get total records  without calling then it's okay the way you are doing

Comment: it returns lastPage but not total number of pages

Comment: lastPage number ?

Comment: yes lastPage Number

Comment: then write a do while loop and check the current page with last page number

Comment: @Eklavya; thanks but am trying to understand if there is any difference between current and suggested solution in terms of efficiency or anything ? :)